# nuxt assign variable to this

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js

I've wrote the following code trying to assign the `setInterval` to `interval` in the data method.

```
data () {
        return {
            page: 1,
            tips: this.$props.data, 
            interval: null
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.interval = setInterval(
            this.poll, 30000
        )
    },
    destroyed(){
        clearInterval(this.interval)
    }
```

Doing so I get the error: `Type 'Timer' is not assignable to type 'null'.` How do I avoid this error and still have to possibility to access the the `interval` variable in `destroyed` method?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not typed your `data` object, it will infer the type for interval from your default value which is null. To get around this issue, we can just type the return value of the `data` object.

We will also need to do a truthy check in the destroyed method now as we need to ensure that `this.interval` is a `NodeJS.Timer` before we can clear the interval as the clearInterval method should never be invoked with a null.

```
export default Vue.extend({
  data(): {
    interval: NodeJS.Timer | null
  } {
    return {
      interval: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    poll(): void {
      console.log('hello!');
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.interval = setInterval(
      this.poll,
      30000
    );
  },
  destroyed(){
    if (this.interval) {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This raises the error Cannot use namespace 'NodeJS' as a value.

Comment: @SanderBakker How did you setup your project? If you followed the create-nuxt-app cli it should not error, install `@types/node` (recommended) or replace `NodeJS.Timer` with `ReturnType<typeof setInterval>`